# How to add a cache clean to my program

Tags: c#, caching

Here is the my c# application, it's a pop up ,i want to know how add cache clean method to this code.

i want to include a cache clean coding to clean cache in this program and minimize the ram

```
namespace SmartAlert
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        static String maxValue = "1";
        static int checkNewRecordTime =8;
        static int frameVisibilityTime = 20;
        private const int CP_DISABLE_CLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer hideTime;



        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkNewRecordTimer();
            checkNewRecord();


        }
        // Method to disable form close button \\
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle | CP_DISABLE_CLOSE_BUTTON;
                return cp;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {


            // Code for set the screen location \\
            var screen = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
            this.Location = new Point(screen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width, screen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height);
            base.OnLoad(e);


        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        // Database record's checking method \\
        // 2
        public void checkNewRecord()
        {
            try {

                var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                String cost_code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["costCenter"].ToString();

                scon.Open();

            SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand();

            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
            string sqlFormattedDate = d1.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            //** query for check and get the last enterd record **\\
            smd.CommandText = "select max(OrdM_No) as M_id from FOOrderMaster where OrdM_Staff ='" + cost_code + "' and OrdM_Date ='" + sqlFormattedDate + "' ";
            smd.Connection = scon;

            SqlDataReader reader = smd.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();
            string mx_id = reader["M_id"].ToString();

            reader.Close();


                if (maxValue != mx_id)
                {
                    maxValue = mx_id;



                    popup_Window(mx_id);
                    this.Show();
                    frameHideTimer();
                }
                scon.Close(); 
                }
            catch (SqlException)
            {

            }            
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
        // Retriving Database record's checking and sending to form method \\
        // 3
        public void popup_Window(String mx_id)
        {
            try
            {

                var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection scon1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                scon1.Open();

                //** query for get the data of last enterd record **\\
                SqlCommand smd1 = new SqlCommand();
                smd1.CommandText = "SELECT f.OrdM_No,f.OrdM_BillNo,f.OrdM_Table,f.OrdM_Date,d.OrdD_Price FROM FOOrderMaster f inner join FOOrderDetail d on f.OrdM_No = d.OrdM_No WHERE f.OrdM_No = '" + mx_id + "'";

                smd1.Connection = scon1;

                    SqlDataReader reader12 = smd1.ExecuteReader();
                    reader12.Read();

                    if (reader12.HasRows)
                    {

                        label8.Text = reader12["OrdM_BillNo"].ToString();
                        label9.Text = reader12["OrdD_Price"].ToString();
                        label7.Text = reader12["OrdM_Table"].ToString();
                        string nm = reader12["OrdM_Date"].ToString();
                        DateTime dm = Convert.ToDateTime(nm);
                        string df = dm.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");                    
                        label6.Text = df.ToString();

                }

                    scon1.Close();

            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {

            }            
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
        // timer for check new record method \\
        // 1
        public void checkNewRecordTimer()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            t.Interval = 1000*checkNewRecordTime; // specify interval time as you want
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            t.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkNewRecord();
        }


        // timer for hidden the form \\
        public void frameHideTimer()
        {
            hideTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            hideTime.Interval = 1000*frameVisibilityTime; // specify interval time as you want
            hideTime.Tick += new EventHandler(hideTimer_Tick);
            hideTime.Start();
        }

        void hideTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            hideTime.Stop();
        }        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                    

            var fm3 = new Form3();
            fm3.Show();
        }

        private void Form2_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var fm3 = new Form3();
            fm3.Show();
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        }
    }



}
```

please help me with this

Comment: Is it really needed to manually 'clean the cache' in your app? Garbage Collection in .NET works automatically

Comment: Add "using" to checkNewRecord then it's good enough